# Install PyTorch without installing Python 3.9 on Win7

Tags: python, pytorch

Got clean installation of Anaconda (Python 3.8.8), tried to install PyTorch by running `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch` as suggested by the docs. The thing is, conda tries to install Python 3.9.7 in the process, which does not support Windows 7 (the famous "api-ms-win-core-path-l1-1-0.dll missing error"). Is there a way to make the installation of PyTorch without switching to the latest Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a clean package with a specific python version you could use the `--freeze-installed` flag to prevent the installer from making any changes to the installed packages, see [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html).